# Issue using git through remote connection

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, scp

I'm trying to access a repository that's located on an internal network at work while i'm at home. The shell that I use to access this internal network doesn't have git, and when accessing the repo using scp I get a "GitLab: Disallowed command" there is also no gcc so i'm not so sure I can compile a portable version from source. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://iofthestorm.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/how-to-use-git-over-scp-without-git-on-the-remote-server/)?

Comment: @Jan, the problem with that approach is that gitlab is enforcing a limited shell. so things like scp/rsync to a git repository will not work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have ssh access to the shell you are using? can you do ssh forwarding?    if so you can do something like

```
ssh -L 2222:ip.of.gitlab:22 user@shellhost
```

and then just use `localhost:2222` as your repository , and ssh will tunnel your connection through the shell host to gitlab repository

Comment: Thanks! This worked well, took me awhile to understand. I tried this earlier with no luck but it seems I was doing something wrong when issuing my git command. This command worked well though.
`git clone ssh://git@localhost:2222/foo/foo.git`